# Why isn't linear search taking more time than binary search?

Tags: c#

When I run my program, I load a list of integers with random numbers, the max I have tried was 500000 numbers (it took a few minutes to load), and then I sort the list with `listName.Sort();`.

The user inputs a number an  I have a 'Linear Search' method that detects if the list contains the number, if yes I make a for loop through every list number and try to find the input number (linear/brute force). And then I print the time difference in milliseconds between the input of the number and the result of the search. But I also have another method for a Binary Search, that does the same thing but instead of a brute-force it makes a binary search.

I tried both searches one at a time expecting the binary search to be way faster, but it turns out both are taking 1 or 2 milliseconds.. What am I doing wrong that it takes so few time?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> arr = new List<int>();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int randomNum;
    DateTime primeira = DateTime.Now;

//here i use 50000 numbers in the array
    for (var i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            //150000 options that don't repeat
            randomNum = rnd.Next(1, 150000);
        } while (arr.Contains(randomNum));
        arr.Add(randomNum);

    }
    arr.Sort();
    DateTime segunda = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan span = segunda - primeira;
    int ms = (int)span.TotalMilliseconds;
    Console.WriteLine($"Load time: {ms}");
    //I use this to know a number to search
    Console.WriteLine($"Biggest: {arr[arr.Count - 1]}"); 
    // search(arr);
    searchBrute(arr);  
}

public static void searchBrute(List<int> arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Insert a number for searching:");

    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(input, out int number))
    {
        if (!arr.Contains(number))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number isn't in the array!");
            searchBrute(arr);
        }
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Count; i++)
        {
            if(number == arr[i])
                showFound(number, i);
        }
        DateTime two = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan test = two - now;
        int msT = (int)test.TotalMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine($"Time taken: {msT}");
    }
}

public static void search(List<int> arr)
{
    bool found;
    int left = 0;
    int right = arr.Count - 1;
    Console.WriteLine("Insert a number for searching:");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    DateTime primeira = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime segunda;
    if (int.TryParse(input, out int number))
    {
        if (!arr.Contains(number))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The number isn't in the array!");
            search(arr);
        }
        do
        {
            found = false;
            int mid = (left + right) / 2;
            if (number == arr[mid])
            {
                found = true;
                showFound(number, mid);

                segunda = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan span = segunda - primeira;
                int ms = (int)span.TotalMilliseconds;
                Console.WriteLine($"Time taken: {ms}");
            }
            else
            {
                if (arr[mid] > number)
                    right = mid - 1;
                else
                    left = mid + 1;

            }
        } while (!found);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats wrong? Using `DateTime` to benchmark is a good place to start (use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`. Followed by making sure you are running the benchmark in release mode with no debugger and optimizations turned on, jitting methods before measuring times, and of course benchmarking more than one search operation to mitigate timing innaccuracies.

Comment: You have to take into account how NET and all the little widgets under the hood do things like optimization.  You need to run more than one iteration and throw the first one away.  It can also pay to retest and do it in the other order.  A StopWatch would be a better way to time it

Comment: Don't use `DateTime`. Instead, use a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`

Comment: Well, you must concider that cpu's can detect loops and fetch cashlines before they are actually needed. Also, the code could be optimized hugely different depending on the different search algorithm. I'm also interested. Have you tried with optimization and whitout a debugger?

Comment: in your binary search, DateTime primeira = DateTime.Now; is in the wrong place. it should be AFTER it find the array has the number. also, need a larger search space.

Comment: What's with the recursive calls?

Comment: Thank you all for the information! I'm really learning a lot here. I know my code may have a lot of errors and wrong things but I'm learning and your points on it really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So. As others have said, use System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch for this timing.

That isn't why the binary search is being slow. Both your search methods contain the line:

```
if (!arr.Contains(number))
```

Which is a linear search. This is probably making the binary search seem unreasonably slow, since it is also O(n) with a linear search inside.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I removed those lines and added a Stopwatch but I may be missing something because it just says it took 0ms... As someone said in a comment above, "Cpu's can detect loops and fetch catchlines before they are actually needed", so I think that's why it is not really searching,,, How can I actually make the search?

Comment: That's probably not the issue. The issue is that the code executed in 0 milliseconds. Your test isn't running enough times to take a whole number of milliseconds.

Comment: Sorry, how could I do that? Should I do a loop in the search or what?

Comment: Just run the search several 1000 times and put the timing outside the search function.

Comment: Ok, so I put a for loop with 1000 iterations before I do my search, either on the linear for loop or do-while binary search loop, then after the 1000-iteration loop I printed the time. That actually worked, but the time seems to be almost the same for both searches. Thanks for that, I learned a lot today.